# Get Windows Version in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, python-os

when i type into the Console(CMD) "winver" i will get my windows version (The four numbers left of the build number, example: 1803,1903,1909,2004,20H2)
But how can i get my windows version in python?
i already tried:

```
import os
os.system("winver")
input()
```

But then it will open a new window like in the cmd, but i just want to print the winver without the rest, therefore i did this:

```
import os
os.system("Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId")
input()
```

But here is the problem that a **string is in a string**.
*"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"*

How can i fix that? Please help!

Comment: FYI... a string in a string is not a problem: you can escape it (`"Reg Query \"...\" /v ReleasedID"`) or just use another type of quotes, like single quotes: `'Reg Query " ..." /v ReleaseID'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**you can use [platform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) module**

```
import platform

print(platform.platform())
print(platform.system())
print(platform.release())
print(platform.version())
print(platform.version().split('.')[2]) 
print(platform.machine())
```

output:

```
Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Windows
10
10.0.19041
19041
AMD64
```

Comment: Hello! thanks but that not what i am searching for, it dont shows me the version i want. i already have a solution, but thanks anyway!

Comment: But what number will "platform.release()" give when I run in Windows 8.1? "81" or "8.1"? (Note: Windows 7 gives "7" instead of "6.1")

Comment: This page shows a list of Windows versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version

Comment: in cygwin  it print other things :/

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the sys library, it has a command just for this.
[Python Docs on sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getwindowsversion)

```
import sys
version = sys.getwindowsversion()
print(version)
print(version[2]) # You can directly reference the build element by index number
print(version.build) # Or by name
```

Output:

```
sys.getwindowsversion(major=10, minor=0, build=19042, platform=2, service_pack='')
19042
19042
```

Answer (score 2):

To put a string inside a string without getting sinttax error you should use single quotes.
The code would look like this:

```
import os
os.system("Reg Query 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' /v ReleaseId")
input()
```

Comment: Oh yess!! That was what i am searching for thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The only registry entry I was able to find that contains the `20H2` value on my system was

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DisplayVersion
```

`Displayversion` is also a REG_SZ value.

Unfortunately I don't know since which Windows 10 version this entry exists. I found some info that on older Windows 10 installations this key was an optional 32bit DWORD value that could be used to show build info, edition, WinDir path on the desktop.

But this is definitely the location where `winver` gets the version info from. If you modify the string winver also shows the modified value.